# Java me game without certificate

Tags: java-me

i have developed Java ME game and now i want to upload it to some of the sites for mobile games. After i finished it, i began to read papers for the producing the final .jar file and .jad file . I mean things like pre-verification , obfuscation , and signing with certificate. My question is specifiaclly for these certificates. If i upload my game and it is not certified ( it is not signed with certificate), will people install it on their phones? I have to mention that i think that i do NOT use some specific java ME api that require an app to be signed in order to used by the phone(I have read that one such api is httpconnection api - well, my game does not use such kind of api). The only thing that i doubt is the usage of RecordStore to store some information, but i think the java me RecordStore does not require the midlets to be signed. Anyway, i will ask in short - if my game is not signed , will people install it on their phone at all? (Just to mention, that the only thing that my game does in general is : paint, re-paint the screen , take the users input from keys, touch screen and use of RecordStore, nothing supernatural for phone game).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing signing does for you, is to remove the security popups you'll otherwise encounter whenever the app tries to access e.g. camera, sms, internet connection or filesystem.

No, you don't need to sign your game, and yes people will install it whether it's signed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Signing is Compulsory for .sis and .sisx files.
J2me games Don't require signing.